# How to decrease a value using FieldValue in Firestore (SWIFT)?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Reading a blog [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html) and the docs, I found that we can increment a value using `FieldValue` but I cound't find a decrement function.

```
document("fitness_teams/Team_1").
  updateData(["step_counter" : FieldValue.decrement(500)]) //Does not exist
```

To decrement a value we still need to use transactions?

Comment: Did you try calling increment with a negative value? `FieldValue.increment(-500)`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need for a decrement function, simply pass a negative value to the actual `increment()` function:

```
document("fitness_teams/Team_1").
  updateData(["step_counter" : FieldValue.increment(-500)])
```

And the value of your `step_counter` field will be decremented by 500.

Comment: Never thought of using an increment function to decrement a value, but it worked, thank you!

Comment: ohh I've never think about this -1,and it worked well

Comment: @RajeshJr. Good to hear that :) Cheers!