# Firestore document relations

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

So I am trying to build a simple shopping solution where I have some products and I want to let people buy them and have order records stored. Since I am new to the NoSQL concepts, I can't really wrap my head around the idea. I can't understand how should I keep track of the amount of products without introducing simultaneous updates. My idea was to have 2 collections, one named `products` and other `orders`. `product` document would have initial amount value and `orders` would have ordered amount. So I would subtract one from another and would get the correct amount of products that way. The problem here is that it seems like a very inefficient way of solving this and my gut feeling says there is a better more appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

A possible database structure for your app might be:

```
Firestore-root
   |
   --- products (collection)
   |     |
   |     --- productId (document)
   |           |
   |           --- quantity: 30
   |           |
   |           --- price: 100
   |           |
   |           --- //Other product properties
   |
   --- orders (collection)
         |
         --- orderId (document)
               |
               --- products: ["productId", "productId", "productId"]
               |
               --- //Other order properties
```

As you can see, there are two different collections, one for products and one for orders. Please note that the `products` property within the `orderId` document is of type array. This means that you can simply add/remove product ids. In Android, you can simply use:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference ordersRef = rootRef.collection("orders");
DocumentReference docIdRef = ordersRef.document(orderId);
docIdRef.update("products", FieldValue.arrayUnion(productId));
```

And to remove, simply use:

```
docIdRef.update("products", FieldValue.arrayRemove(productId));
```

Once a order is finished, just get all product id and decrement the quantity of each product using my answer from the following post:

- [How to decrease a value using FieldValue in Firestore (SWIFT)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934484/how-to-decrease-a-value-using-fieldvalue-in-firestore-swift/55934520#55934520)

Comment: Hi Nick and sorry to see that your question was put on hold. Hope I understood what you asked. So have you tried my solution above?